# Recyleview sometimes add new item to the top

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm adding a new layout to RecycleView on click of a plus button of the previous layout. At first, I'm adding empty data to model class and setting the adapter with one item. After that click of the button, I need to add the second item and so on.

Problem is . at first it works and recyclview with one item is display. on click of button second layout is also added below first. but a third time if I click on that button. it is adding a new item to the top of Recycleview. I need to generate a vertical hierarchy.

Adding First Data  on onCreate

```
var arrayList:ArrayList<SubjectModel> = ArrayList()

        var model = SubjectModel()
        arrayList.add(model)

        var adapter = SubjectListAdapter(arrayList)

        var layoutManager  = LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)

        rv_subject.layoutManager = layoutManager
        rv_subject.adapter = adapter
```

And inside the adapter. I have a plus button which is adding new item vertically.

```
      holder.img_delete_subject.setTag(position);
    holder.img_delete_subject.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            if (if it is plus ) {

                holder.img_delete_subject.setImageResource(minus image);

                data.add(data.size(),new SubjectModel());
                notifyItemInserted((data.size() - 1));

            } else {

                data.remove(Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString()));
              notifyItemRemoved(Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString()));

            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: How do you know which one is newly added? It is just a new SubjectModel() and are same to all rows.

Comment: @AIMINPAN i'm using `edittext watcher` and setting data at that position with `onTextchangedListner`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `notifiyDataSetChanged()`. As documentation says:

```
         * <p>This event does not specify what about the data set has changed, forcing
         * any observers to assume that all existing items and structure may no longer be valid.
         * LayoutManagers will be forced to fully rebind and relayout all visible views.</p>
```

When you add single item to the list, you should be using

```
notifyItemInsterted(position: Int)
```

```
        /**
         * Notify any registered observers that the item reflected at <code>position</code>
         * has been newly inserted. The item previously at <code>position</code> is now at
         * position <code>position + 1</code>.
         *
         * <p>This is a structural change event. Representations of other existing items in the
         * data set are still considered up to date and will not be rebound, though their
         * positions may be altered.</p>
         *
         * @param position Position of the newly inserted item in the data set
```

Comment: I'll try and let you know

Comment: I've added `notifyItemInsterted` and its working now . one last question .  I've  updated my adapter code. when i remove data from my `data` and click on plus .it adding new item with old data again .(I've made sure it removed from the list properly). would be very helpful if you can help . nevertheless i'll accept this answer.

Comment: I'll add other info if you need.